why do we use the initial pressure and final volume to calculate enthalpy change?
$\Delta H= \Delta U + P\Delta V +V\Delta P$
Why is the change of enthalpy equal to the change of internal energy + P(initial) times the change in volume + V(final) times the change in enthalpy.
I know how this formula is derived, but I'm confused of why we use the initial pressure and final volume to calculate the change in enthalpy.

Does writing it as $\Delta H= \Delta U + \Delta ( PV)$ help?

im still confused why they used initial pressure and final volume

Your first equation is incorrect.

In context of physical chemistry, the implicit(=missing) indexes at state variables mean that all state variables describe the same system state, whatever the state is. E.g. in the famous $pV=nRT$, $p$ cannot be the initial pressure, $V$ intermediate volume and $T$ final temperature.
If one wants to express state variables at different system states in the same equation, there must be used explicit indexes, denoting the state.
$$\Delta H = \Delta U + \Delta (pV) \ne \Delta U + p  \Delta V + V  \Delta p \tag{1}$$
$$\Delta (pV) = (p + \Delta p)(V + \Delta V) - pV = p  \Delta V + V  \Delta p + \Delta p  \Delta V \tag{2}$$
This equation  can be rearranged by two different ways:
$$\Delta (pV) = (p + \Delta p)\Delta V + V\Delta p = p_\mathrm{final} \Delta V + V_\text{initial}\Delta p \tag{3}$$
$$\Delta (pV) = (V + \Delta V)\Delta p + p\Delta V = V_\mathrm{final} \Delta p + p_\text{initial}\Delta V \tag{4}$$
If the equation was in the differential state,
$$\text{d}H = \text{d}U + \text{d}(pV) = \text{d}U + p \cdot \text{d}V + V \cdot \text{d}p + \text{d}p \cdot \text{d}V  \tag{5}$$
then the last term would be neglected and there would be no need to distinguish the states.
$$\text{d}H = \text{d}U + \text{d}(pV) = \text{d}U + p \cdot \text{d}V + V \cdot \text{d}p \tag{6}$$

thank you sir, i understand it now. it seems that i have confused the differential state with the state variable. i neglected the last term of ΔpΔV and got lost there.

The equation $\Delta H=\Delta U+p\Delta V+V\Delta p$, unlike its equivalent
with differentials, is not correct even though it appears in some
introductory textbooks. I find the easiest way to think about this (and
similar equations) is to start with the definition of enthalpy
$$
H=U+pV
$$
So at the final and initial states we have
$$
H_{\mathrm{f}}=U_{\mathrm{f}}+p_{\mathrm{f}}V_{\mathrm{f}}
$$
$$
H_{\mathrm{i}}=U_{\mathrm{i}}+p_{\mathrm{i}}V_{\mathrm{i}}
$$
Now $\Delta $ means final minus initial, so subtracting we have
$$
\Delta H=\Delta U+p_{\mathrm{f}}V_{\mathrm{f}}-p_{\mathrm{i}}V_{\mathrm{i}}
$$
For a change in which the initial and final pressures are the same value $p$, i.e., $p_{\mathrm{f}}=p_{\mathrm{i}}=p$, then
$$
\Delta H=\Delta U+pV_{\mathrm{f}}-pV_{\mathrm{i}}=\Delta U+p(V_{\mathrm{f}%
}-V_{\mathrm{i}})=\Delta U+p\Delta V
$$
For a change in which the initlal and final volumes are the same value $V$,
i.e., $V_{\mathrm{f}}=V_{\mathrm{i}}=V$, then
$$
\Delta H=\Delta U+p_{\mathrm{f}}V-p_{\mathrm{i}}V=\Delta U+V(p_{\mathrm{f}%
}-p_{\mathrm{i}})=\Delta U+V\Delta p
$$
But if both $p$ and $V$ are changing, we have to stick with $\Delta H=\Delta
U+p_{\mathrm{f}}V_{\mathrm{f}}-p_{\mathrm{i}}V_{\mathrm{i}}$.
People get away with using $\Delta H=\Delta U+p\Delta V+V\Delta p$ because
in the next step they inevitably remove one of the $p\Delta V$ or $V\Delta p$
terms to get a correct result. However, it doesn't apply in general, it
leads to the sort of confusion the questioner had, and so it should not be
used.
